# ¿Como puedo convertir documentos de Office en base 64 a PDF en base 64 en C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, microsoft-office

Estoy realizando un proceso de migración entre 2 bases de datos y en la base de datos origen existen registros en tablas que contienen documentos en base 64 (Excel y Word) y me han pedido que en la base de datos destino los guarde como PDF en base 64 tambien.

El problema lo tengo en la conversión... En la origen he detactado los siguientes tipos de documentos:

- data:application/msword;base64,0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7...
- data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/...
- data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQB8bJgWbAEAAKA...
- data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQAJJIeCgQEAAI4F...

Al final todos tienen que acabar con el siguiente formato:

- data:application/pdf;base64,0M8R4KGxGuEAAA...

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacer esta conversión directamente en memoria? Ya que aparte de que todo se almacene en PDF, otro requisito es este, que no se cree ningún archivo temporal.

Espero alguno lo haya echo alguna vez y me pueda ayudar ya que estoy completamente perdido.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Saludos Alejandro, me sorprende que teniendo 99 puntos de reputación, 1 medalla de plata y 14 de bronce, realices una pregunta así, puesto que claramente es un "necesito esto", sin mostrar algo que hayas investigado algo, recuerda que la comunidad atiende mejor las preguntas que contienen intentos de haber querido realizar la solución. Por otro lado, ¿Por qué cargar la base de datos con archivos? ¿Por qué guardados en base64? Hacer una transformación así como la planteas podría funcionar para archivos de word, para Excel no lo recomiendo, considera que se puede distorcionar el formato.

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx... lo de la base de datos es una migracion entre aplicaciones... ya estaban asi guardados los documentos y no puedo cambiarlo... son requerimientos del cliente que esten asi tanto en una como en otra BD... Por otro lado, lo que comentas de las pruebas, si que he realizado con iTextSharp pero generaba un documento tempora y me dijeron que no podia crear archivos... haciendolo todo en memoria no lo hice nunca porque me lo dijeron el viernes a ultima hora...

Comment: Mañana intentare hacer esas pruebas a ver como lo hago... Lo puse aqui por si alguien lo habia hecho, pues tener una idea de como lo hace, que libreria usa... E ir mas directo a la solucion ya que se me echaba el tiempo encima...

Comment: Hice algo parecido hace tiempo : leer varios archivos pdf y fusionarlos en uno solo. Utilicé concurrentbag para trabajarlos en paralelo. Te recomiendo que primero hagas una lectura de los archivos en memoria y que luego los proceses. Ten cuidado que olvides colocar las referencias de las tablas

Answer (score 1):

Encontre una librería de pago que realiza esta conversión y ademas, tiene una gratuita, Spiro.Office. Con muy pocas lineas de código consigo hacer una transformación, por ejemplo, de un word en base64 a un pdf en base64, que es lo que necesito.

```
byte[] byteArrayInput = Convert.FromBase64String(test);
MemoryStream streamInput = new MemoryStream(byteArrayInput);
MemoryStream streamOutput = new MemoryStream();

Spire.Doc.Document document = new Spire.Doc.Document();
document.LoadFromStream(streamInput, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.Docx);
document.SaveToStream(streamOutput, Spire.Doc.FileFormat.PDF);

byte[] byteArrayOutput = streamOutput.ToArray();
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArrayOutput);
```

El incoveniente es que la librería es de pago y la licencia es bastante cara. Buscaba una solución similar pero con alguna librería gratuita, ya que con esta, si uso la version de pago sin licencia, mete en el pdf marcas de texto a montones, y si uso la versión gratuita, solo convierte las 3 primeras paginas además de incluir un mensaje grande rojo al final diciendo que la versión gratuita no permite convertir mas y que se debe pagar la licencia.

¿Alguno conoce alguna librería alternativa que sea gratis?